# std::formatter c++ 20 with union and struct

Tags: c++, struct, c++20, unions, stdformat

Is there any reason why `std::format` doesn't compile using a data type like this one:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

typedef union MIDI_EVENT_type_u
{
    uint8_t val;
    struct {
        uint8_t low : 4;
        uint8_t high : 4;
    };
} MIDI_EVENT_type_u;
```

using `std::format` to print the `uint8_t` value works only for the `val` above, the `low` and `high` are not compiling and must be casted to an unsigned int.

Is there any reason for that as `std::format` is fed with a `uint8_t`?

e.g.

```cpp
MIDI_EVENT_type_u type = {0};
auto a = std::format("{}", type.val);
auto b = std::format("{}", type.high); // error
auto c = std::format("{}", type.low);  // error
```

the error is:

```
no instance of overloaded function "std::format" matches the argument list
argument types are: (const char [3], uint8_t)
```

Is there a way to write a custom `std::formatter` to do the cast to unsigned automatically in this case?

Besides, It is not clear why the value in the "`union.struct`" are not compiled even if are detected as `uint8_t`, any reason for that?

---

**EXTENSION:**

After the answer and comments from @user17732522 (thanks), for this particulat case there are these kind of solution (at least for compiling, not sure if it will resolve type punning completely):

changing that struct, when is possible to something like:

```cpp
typedef union MIDI_EVENT_type_u
{
    uint8_t val;
    // the struct also give it a name and put private would be better.
    struct {
        uint8_t low : 4;
        uint8_t high : 4;
    };
    constexpr uint8_t getHigh() { return high; };
    constexpr uint8_t getLow() { return low; };

} MIDI_EVENT_type_u;
```

and using the `getHigh()` and `getLow()` method will resolve the compilation error, or even using a global constexpr to return the .high or .low values eventually.

It looks to me that is something missing in C++ to deal with this scenario that is kind of a basic use case since C '70s...

ERGO: the C++ in this case could also "auto generate" or defaulting to do something like those 2 extra constexpr, no need to be such verbose in writing code, in my opinion.

---

instead if that is a C struct that can't be modified:

```cpp
typedef union MIDI_EVENT_type_u
{
    uint8_t val;
    struct {
        uint8_t low : 4;
        uint8_t high : 4;
    };
} MIDI_EVENT_type_u;
 constexpr uint8_t get(const uint8_t val) { return val; };
```

in this way it will also compile `std::format("{}", get(type.low));`
It looks excessevily verbose to do "basic operations" that where always working in C/C++ in older time, I don't really understand that.

Is this something changed in the modern C++ standard and was once instead supported?

If the latter is the case shouldn't be considered on the next C++ iteration to support such base cases and make the compiler generating underneath such simple boilerplate code as it can just be resolved with a constexpr getting a type and returning the same type?

Comment: NOTE: I have "extended" the original question as it has become a broader topic to understand rather than just the simple scenario of the why not compiling std::format with union members

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::format` takes its arguments by-reference (specifically as forwarding reference).

A bit-field can't be passed by reference. So you do need to first convert to a prvalue of some type from which then a temporary object can be materialized to which the reference parameter can be bound, e.g. by writing

```
std::format("{}", uint8_t{type.high});
```

or if you don't want to repeat the type:

```
std::format("{}", decltype(type.high){type.high});
```

With C++23 you can use the new `auto` syntax:

```
std::format("{}", auto{type.high});
```

You will have this problem with a huge part of the standard library when using bit-fields. The standard library typically takes generic arguments by forwarding reference.

Bit-fields do not behave like normal class members or objects and are pretty much second-class to them. I'd suggest avoiding bit-fields or writing accessor member functions that return you the value so that you can use them directly. If this is a C API, then I'd suggest writing a proper C++ API around it first.

---

Also, the syntax using an anonymous `struct` is not standard C++. A `union` can be anonymous, but a `struct` cannot, in standard C++. However, compilers are likely to support this in C++ as an extension, because it is valid syntax in C11.

Also, accessing `type.high` and `type.low` causes undefined behavior according to the standard because `val` is the active member of the union and only the active member may be read. Type punning with unions is not possible. However compilers typically support this as an extension, because it has defined behavior in C, but even then layout of bit-fields is implementation-defined and e.g. the order in which bit fields are packed into bytes is implementation-dependent, and so is the result of reading these inactive members.

Also, assuming this is not a C API, `typedef union MIDI_EVENT_type_u { /*...*/ } MIDI_EVENT_type_u;` is completely redundant in C++. Just `union MIDI_EVENT_type_u { /*...*/ };` is enough.

Comment: how can i do this for the example above ? ` writing accessor member functions that return you the value so that you can use them directly.`  Do i have to specialize std::formatter template?

Comment: @Raffaello No, just mark the members of `MIDI_EVENT_type_u` as `private:` and add a member function to it like `uint8_t getHigh() const { return high; }`, then use `std::format("{}", type.getHigh());`

Comment: what about if that is a C union/struct shared for a 3rd party library?

Comment: @Raffaello Then write C++ classes/functions that wrap all of the C library to provide that interface. Typically this involves some larger design considerations. For example you would also want to design the C++ API so that it properly uses RAII, which the C API can't.

Comment: @Raffaello Or as a quicker workaround, make the function a free one: `uint8_t getHigh(const MIDI_EVENT_type_u& x) { return x.high; }` and then `std::format("{}", getHigh(type));`. But that doesn't feel very clean.

Comment: is it wrong to do a static_cast<unsigned int>(type.low) instead? 
Also would it be better getting rid off the union in modern C++ (C++20) ?

Comment: @Raffaello Noone™ uses `union`s in C++ anymore. `std::variant` is preferred, but `static_cast<unsigned int>(type.low)` works if that's the active member. If `val` is the active member, reading `low` has UB.

Comment: @Raffaello `static_cast<unsigned int>(type.low)` also works (except for the UB of accessing an inactive member as I discussed in my answer), however: 1. You are casting to a different type than you declared `type.low` to be. Why this dependency? 2. `static_cast<T>(/*...*/)` allows for more conversions than `T{/*...*/}` does, so the risk of making a mistake is smaller with the latter syntax. In particular it will complain about narrowing casts.

Comment: @Raffaello  Regarding unions: Generally yes, but your use case (something similar to type-punning) isn't proper standard C++ anyway and there is no standard analogue to it. In standard C++ you would just get the high and low bits with normal arithmetic from `val` (e.g. in a member function).

Comment: @TedLyngmo `std::variant` won't help here. The union isn't used as a tagged union that `std::variant` could replace.

Comment: @user17732522 True. One would have to keep track of the active member somewhere else or just make sure to not read from a non-active memer.

Comment: what about using a constexpr rather than a "free function" in that case could help dealing with type puning?

on this case would be better doing bitwise operation and rid off the union? as high and low basically are 0xF bitwise and operation on val? On the other  hand instead of falling back to esplicitly delcaring the bitwise operation on the active member (even through a constexpr) is there a modern c++ way to deal with that "automatically" like the use of a union struct combination in this example above? (btw thanks for the answer and commnets so far)

Comment: one last bit that i completely don't understand is why in C++  union types can be defined and used, but if the non active member is accessed it can result in UB .... why?
I mean is like giving you a car that if you put the 6th gear you may break the engine and forcing to use until the 5th .... i think i miss some information on that, because it looks quite silly.

Comment: @Raffaello What is "_a constexpr_"? Do you mean a `constexpr` function? If so, yes it makes sense to declare the function `constexpr`, but it isn't likely going to be important for optimization. What's important for optimization is that the function is defined in each translation unit that uses it, i.e. that it is defined in the header as `inline` (which is implicit with `constexpr` or when defined inside a class definition).

Comment: @Raffaello "_is there a modern c++ way to deal with that "automatically" like the use of a union struct combination in this example above?_": No, but it is trivial to write a function with the same behavior. The bit field approach does the same anyway, only that the compiler implements it and with the disadvantage that the behavior is implementation-defined and so the code is less portable.

Comment: "_but if the non active member is accessed it can result in UB .... why?_": The main point of a union is to allow you to hold objects of different types at different times in the same storage. In modern C++, except when you have very specific requirements, these use cases can be made type-safe by replacing them with `std::variant`. Using it for type-punning is a secondary, highly implementation-dependent, use case that wasn't adopted for C++. C++ focuses more than C on defining semantics in terms of values of objects, not how these values are represented in memory.

Comment: @Raffaello However, C++20 has `std::bit_cast` which allows you to do reinterpretation of the object representation (i.e. bits in memory) of an object into another value of different type. In contrast to type punning with unions or aliasing-violating `reinterpret_cast` constructs, it has well-defined behavior according to the standard with the usual limitations imposed by implementation-definedness of object representations. It also can only be used on types where such a reinterpretation makes sense (i.e. trivially-copyable types which isn't a restriction that is necessary in C).